# open banner overlay when the page is loaded with fancybox 4

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I would like to update to the latest version of fancybox 4 the javascript code of my banner overlay that opens when the page is loaded.
I don't understand where I'm wrong.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
  if(!Cookies.get('overlay2533'))
  {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      Fancybox.show([
        {
          src : "#fancybox-overlay",
          type : "image"
        }
      ]);
    });
    var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(24,0,0,0);

    Cookies.set("overlay2533", "1", { expires: new Date( date ) });
  }
})(jQuery);
</script>

<div id="fancybox-overlay" style="display:none;">
  <href="htts://....." target="_blank"><img src="https://....."  alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you see in console?

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 27,
  "colno": 4
}

Comment: you didn't load jQuery library to your project. But i ask about console your project not snippet.

Comment: these are the libraries present:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0.4/dist/fancybox.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0.4/dist/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>

Comment: this is the test page where I am doing the tests:
https://www.sanremonews.it/prove

Comment: sorry I only reported the useful elements for the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/t2xwsfrd/1/

Comment: on jsfiddle all working good

Comment: the console does not report javascript errors but unfortunately the overlay image is not displayed.
The text "Image not found" appears.

Comment: try change `type : "image"` to `type : "clone"` (or `inline`) div with id `"#fancybox-overlay` is not an image

Comment: thank you so much
actually it was enough type: inline and it loads correctly